# Mongoose schema option change doesn't reflect in database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a mongoose schema defined like the following one:

```
{
    Username: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true,
    },
    Password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minlength: 10,
        maxlength: 20
    }
}
```

For example after we launch the production build of our app which is running live, if I want to change "unique" to `unique: false` for the "Username" how should I do it?

So on my machine when the server is running i created a User with Username and Password, mongo created User for me, now i changed the Unique Option value to `unique: false` manually in the code and restarted my server, mongo throws an error saying `"E11000 duplicate key error collection: TFM-Dev-Server.admins index: Username_1 dup key: { Username: \"admin\" }"`. But I did change Unique option to false. Only when I drop my database it works. But I can't keep on dropping my production database with User Data for a small change as this. Someone please tell me how to implement the best way.

In my app Schemas change very often in few areas of my app, I want to deal them without stopping & dropping database of my production server.

Thanks

Comment: Instead of dropping db, can't you drop index ? `db.collection.dropIndexes()`

Comment: Just drop the unique index (which got created by defining it in the mongoose schema) for `Username`: either by `db.collection.dropIndex("Username_1");` or `db.runCommand( { dropIndexes: "collection", index: "Username_1" });`

Answer (score 3):

**Why you are having the error:**
The first time you created the schema with `unique: true`, mongoose will auto-create a unique index for the field(i.e `Username`). When you change it from within your code to `unique: false`, the change won't undo what mongoose had done, the unique index would still be in the database. So whenever you try to insert another document with a Username that already exists(even after toggling the unique option to `false`), you will get the index duplicate key error.

**The solution:**
Firstly, you should know that the `unique` option is not a way to validate or enforce the `Username` field to be unique but rather it's a helper for building MongoDB unique indexes. [Source](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#the-unique-option-is-not-a-validator).
If you are using the `unique` option for validation, then the right thing to do would be to remove it and implement other logic to ensure the uniqueness of the `Username` field. However, if you are deliberate about using the `unique` option to auto-create indexes, then you need to drop the unique indexes whenever you toggle the `unique` option to false. You can do that with this in the mongo shell:

```
db.Admin.dropIndex( { "Username" : -1 } )
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because `mongoose` has created a unique index automatically when you first define the unique field.

You can drop index via mongodb command:

```
db.pets.dropIndex( { "cat" : -1 } )
```

Read more [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.dropIndex/)

or via `mongoose`, like this (you need to change this to adapt to your project)

```
var Driver = mongoose.model('admins', DriverSchema);
// Dropping an Index in MongoDB
Driver.collection.dropIndex('Username', function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Error in dropping index!', err);
    }
});
module.exports = Driver;
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I did adapt the code that you provided like the following:

`Admin.collection.dropIndex('Username', function(err, result) {
        if(err) console.log('Error ind dropping index!', err)
        console.log(result)
})`

Where "Admin" is the mongoose model. When I run the code I get error saying:

`Error in dropping index! MongoError: index not found with name [Username]
errmsg: 'index not found with name [Username]',
  code: 27,
  codeName: 'IndexNotFound',
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {}`

Comment: @UPrashanth The index name is `Username_1` and not `Username`. change that in the code and that should work