# How do i check if same name or same number already exist in mongodb database?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I wanted to check if name or number already exists in dtatbase, if it exists, then i dont want to create a new User and display an error message. This is my userSchema:

```
var userSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
    name:String,
    age: Number, 
    gender: String, 
    number: Number,
    location: String
    });
var User =mongoose.model("user",userSchema);
```

Post request for creating a new user:

```
app.post("/user",function(req,res){
       const name=req.body.name,
           age=req.body.age,
           gender=req.body.gender,
           number=req.body.number,
           location=req.body.location;
    //creating new object with all details
    const newUser={
        name:name,
        age:age,
        gender:gender,
        number:number,
        location:location
    }
    User.create(newUser,function(err,newlyCreatedUser){
        if(err)
        {res.send("Unable to create new user");}
        else
        {res.send(newlyCreatedUser); }
    });
```

Till now this code creates a new user, how can i change it so that to check BOTH name and number and create ONLY IF both of them are unique?

Answer (score 1):

use the following userSchema

```
var userSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
    type: String,
    unique: true
    },
    age: Number, 
    gender: String, 
    number: {
    type: Number,
    unique: true
    },
    location: String
    });
```

After changing userSchema goto the project directory and turn off the server. Now use the following command to drop the database (**if it contains important data then avoid it**).

```
mongodbconnection.connection.db.dropDatabase(
console.log("database dropped.")
);
```

where `mongodbconnection` is the instance of `mongoose` created using the following command.

```
const mongodbconnection = require("mongoose");
```

Now run the server again and it is done

Comment: Hi what do u mean by drop the existing dtabase? Thank you @Zain Ul Abideen

Comment: Hi if my database contains important data how to go about it? willonly updating the schema work? @Zain Ul Abideen

Comment: Also on changing the user schema it gives this warning: DeprecationWarning: collection.ensureIndex is deprecated. Use createIndexes instead. And even on changing the userSchema, its still accepting users with same name @Zain Ul Abideen

Comment: upload the database connection code in the question.

Comment: [Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59599830/mongoose-schema-option-change-doesnt-reflect-in-database) for further clarification